# reloading the masonry container after showing new items doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

having a bit of an issue here. I need to have a bunch of items hidden when the site first loads, and only appear after I click a button. At the top of my doc.ready I have this:

```
$('#showall').hide();
```

which successfully hides the cards I need hidden (obviously). then I tried to unhide them and reload the masonry container but it doesn't seem to be working..

```
var container = document.querySelector('.comparison-cards');
var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
    // options
    itemSelector: '.card',
    gutter: 20,
    isFitWidth: true
});

$('.button').click(function () {
    $('#showall').show();
    msnry.reloadItems();
});
```

Is there any reason why this wouldn't work? Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this? For clarification, the cards I have hidden have the same class as the cards I have initially showing just a different id.

Thanks for any help you may provide! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by a combination of using jquery show() and hide() and masonry remove() and addItems():

```
    $('.button').click(function () {

    if (buttonClicked == false) {
        $(testArray).show();
        msnry.addItems(testArray);
        $(container).append(testArray);
        msnry.appended(testArray);
        msnry.reloadItems();
        msnry.layout();
        $('.button').html('SHOW LESS');
        buttonClicked = true;
        console.log(buttonClicked);
    } else {
        msnry.remove(testArray);
        msnry.layout();
        $('.button').html('SHOW ALL');
        buttonClicked = false;
        console.log(buttonClicked);
    }

});
```